# Replace the attribute of an object literal by a variable

Tags: javascript

I have an object literal with a list of countries with two values, price and name:
[image]

When the select changes I store the values of the current selected country:
[image]

And I store this value in the variable inner function .change():

```
current_country = $('#country').val();
```

I accessed this way the object literal for example `countries_list.deu`

But when I use my current_country Variable console shows me what undefined:

```
 console.log(countries_list.current_country);
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: Can we have js fiddle please?

Comment: No... is a project with laravel

Comment: I edited the main post with other screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Use **selectedIndex** to get the selected value index and use **.options[i].value** to get the value of the option with the following index:

```
var countries = document.getElementById("country");
var current_country = countries.options[countries.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be using bracket notation

```
console.log(countries_list[current_country]);
```

In your case, it actually looks for the property named `current_country` within the object, where it doesn't exist.

Look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4968448/1592398) for better understanding of two different notations